# Specifying a volume type for an ec2 instance when running aws ec2 run-instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ebs

I want to specify GP3 as the volume type of my root EBS volume as I launch the instance. This is the command that I ran

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
--region us-east-2 \
--image-id ami-0e361731ae5aacece \
--instance-type c4.large \
--key-name my-key \
--block-device-mappings file://block-device-mappings.json \
--placement file://placement.json \
--monitoring file://monitoring.json \
--disable-api-termination \
--monitoring file://monitoring.json \
--instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior terminate \
--network-interfaces file://network-interfaces.json \
--iam-instance-profile file://iam-instance-profile.json \
--ebs-optimized \
--tag-specifications file://tag-specifications.json
```

Below is the content of my `block-device-mappings.json`

```
[
    {
        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
        "Ebs": {
            "VolumeSize": 50,
            "DeleteOnTermination": false,
            "VolumeType": "gp3"
        }
    }
]
```

This [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html#Using_ChangeRootDeviceVolumeToPersist) was used when creating the above JSON

But when I run the above command, it fails because I am using a corporate account which does not allow creating EC2 instances with GP2 volume type. Why is GP3 not being used as the volume type although it is explicitly specified?

EDIT 1:

This is the error message that I get after I decode the encoded failure message (note that I have removed some items from the `PrincipalArn` object and added dummy values where necessary account id etc.)

```
{
    "allowed": false,
    "explicitDeny": true,
    "matchedStatements": {
        "items": [
            {
                "statementId": "RestrictEC2Volume",
                "effect": "DENY",
                "principals": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "value": "MY_ROLE_ACCESS_KEY"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "principalGroups": {
                    "items": []
                },
                "actions": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "value": "ec2:RunInstances"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "ec2:CreateVolume"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "resources": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "value": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "conditions": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "key": "ec2:VolumeType",
                            "values": {
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "gp2"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "aws:PrincipalArn",
                            "values": {
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "arn:aws:sts::12345678:assumed-role/EMR_DefaultRole/CCSSession"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "arn:aws:sts::4567890:assumed-role/EMR_DefaultRole/CCSSession"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "arn:aws:iam::3456789:role/EMR_DefaultRole"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "arn:aws:iam::4567890:role/EMR_DefaultRole"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "arn:aws:sts::567890876:assumed-role/EMR_DefaultRole/CCSSession"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "arn:aws:iam::567890876:role/EMR_DefaultRole"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "arn:aws:iam::234567854:role/EMR_DefaultRole"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "arn:aws:sts::234567854:assumed-role/EMR_DefaultRole/CCSSession"
                                    },
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "failures": {
        "items": []
    },
    "context": {
        "principal": {
            "id": "MY_ROLE_ACCESS_KEY:INSTANCE_ID",
            "arn": "arn:aws:sts::ACCT_ID:assumed-role/AWS-SSM-AgentAccess/MY_ROLE_ACCESS_KEY:INSTANCE_ID"
        },
        "action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:ACCT_ID:volume/*",
        "conditions": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "key": "aws:Resource",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "volume/*"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Account",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "ACCT_ID"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:AvailabilityZone",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "us-east-2b"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:Encrypted",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "false"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:VolumeType",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "gp2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:IsLaunchTemplateResource",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "false"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Region",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "us-east-2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Service",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "ec2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:VolumeID",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "*"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:VolumeSize",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "10"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:ParentSnapshot",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2::snapshot/SNAPSHOT_ID"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:Type",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "volume"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "ec2:Region",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "us-east-2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "aws:ARN",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:ACCT_ID:volume/*"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, if I understand this message correctly, I can see that it is trying to create a 10GB volume with type GP2 although I have specified 50GB volume of type GP3

Comment: Can you share the failure error that you mentioned?

Comment: @Lucasz please check updated question

Comment: "it fails " - is not specific. What is exact error message?

Comment: @Marcin the question was updated with the failure message 6 hours ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your AMI, the [root drive name varies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html#available-ec2-device-names). You are using `/dev/sda1`, but for example, on amazon linux 2 it should be `/dev/xvda`:

```
[
    {
        "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
        "Ebs": {
            "VolumeSize": 50,
            "DeleteOnTermination": false,
            "VolumeType": "gp3"
        }
    }
]
```

If you use `sda1`, your root is still gp2, as you just create new, separate drive called `sda1` alongside `xvda`.

Comment: Perfect. I used `aws ec2 describe-images` to find the root drive name and used that. Thanks!

Comment: @user538578964 No problem. Glad it worked :-)